# How do I determine which conf file mongodb is using?

Tags: macos, mongodb, homebrew

I installed mongodb through Homebrew. The configuration file is located in `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`. If I type `mongod` into the terminal it will fail to find that conf file. So I'm left wondering what conf file it's using by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you always need to set the config file. There is no default one. Brew tells you as much when you do `brew info mongodb`, then it says that you can run mongod using the `--config` option. So I ended up creating an alias so I don't have to worry about setting the config every time.

Comment: Or you can use http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.serverCmdLineOpts/#db.serverCmdLineOpts I am pretty sure this question is a duplicate actually

Comment: When I searched stackoverflow I couldn't find a satisfying answer. When you start `mongod` without setting a conf file you it complains that the dbpath is not set.